# NotificationCompat.Builder notification issue

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'm trying to add a Notification to my app.

The API level is 8, so, I need to use NotificationCompat instead of Notification, needn't I?

this is my code:

```
  NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
  NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
```

But, there is an error, "cannot be solved as a type"

Where is the mistake

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure your import statement is such for compatibility.

```
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat
```

Comment: NotificationCompat is not included in android-support-v4.jar (at least in mine), should I download another jar file?

Comment: Yes, download the Android Support Library.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the v4 support library in the *build.gradle* file under the `dependencies` section in order to be able to import the needed `android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat` class:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    ...
}
```

This essentially downloads the support library from the Android Support Repository, assuming that you have already installed the mentioned repo from the SDK Manager. More details [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html).